# notBetween ecto query

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have a query which return the results `between` the `values` we passed into it in the params if we passed `[value1, value2]` like this:

```
  where: field(name) > ^Enum.min(value 1)
  and field(name) < ^Enum.max(value 2)
```

Its returning the records between `value1` and `value 2`.

I want to implement `notbetween`. which will return records `less than value1` and `greater than value 2`

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> will return records `less than value1` and `greater than value 2`

Just reverse the condition (note `or` to return either those less, or those greater):

```
where: field(name) < ^Enum.min(value 1)
    or field(name) > ^Enum.max(value 2)
```